# C++ successful `try` branch

Tags: c++, try-catch

Let's consider some artificial C++ code:

```
int i = 0;

try { someAction(); }
catch(SomeException &e) { i = -1; }

i = 1;

... // code that uses i
```

I want this code to assign `-1` to `i` in case of `someAction()` throws exception and assign `1` in case if there was no exception. As you can see now this code is wrong because `i` finally always becomes `1`. Sure, we can make some trick workarounds like:

```
int i = 0;
bool throwed = false;

try { someAction(); }
catch(SomeException &e) { throwed = true; }

i = throwed ? -1 : 1;

... // code that uses i
```

My question is: is there anything in C++ like "successful try branch", where I do some actions in case if there were no any throws in try block?
Something like:

```
int i = 0;

try { someAction(); }
catch(SomeException &e) { i = -1; }
nocatch { i = 1; }

... // code that uses i
```

Surely, there is no `nocatch` in C++ but maybe there is some common beautiful workaround?

Comment: The "nocatch" is called "try".

Comment: You can have more than one line of code within a try or catch block.

Comment: One way is to initialize `i` to `1`. That's the simplest. Another way is to put your code in a function (e.g. a lambda) and return the `i` value.

Comment: See this for a credible implementation of the try catch finally idiom you see in Java for example: https://gist.github.com/karagog/ab41468ea82a8fb54cde IMHO the answers thus far are smelly. I'd say that the approach in the link is beautiful. Requires C++11 though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int i = 0;

try { someAction(); i = 1; }
catch(SomeException &e) { i = -1; }
```

Comment: Just initialize `i` to `1`. No need for fragile placement of assignment. EDIT: I don't understand the upvotes of an answer that is so short and still needlessly advocates fragile code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You're right that initializing `i` to `1` is simpler, but can you help me understand why this code is fragile?

Comment: @AndyG: It relies on the assignment to `i` being last in the `try` block, after all that can throw. Maintenance might change that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: On the other hand, if the point is to check that all which might throw did not throw, that location is exactly the right place. Changing that in maintenance would be a rather bold move.

Comment: @MSalters: Things are changed in maintenance for reasons one cannot fathom, without real understanding of how the code works. Or at least that was my experience in the 1990s and early 2000s. I've been out of the game. But it was particularly unpleasant for C functions that needed to clean up in all paths that could return. Happily with C++ we can automate things, reduce the *possibility*, and that's what we IMO should do.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the simple solution

```
try
{
  someAction();
  i = 1;
}
catch(SomeException &e)
{
  i = -1;
}
```

you should consider what you are planning to do with the value of `i` further in the code - use it in `if` statements? That is poor design, you could simply put all the code inside the braces after `try` and `catch` respectively.

Comment: I don't think that code snippet says anything about design. If I remember correctly, at that point I used a third-party library which used exceptions quite excessively - on every-every situation, even objectively non-error ones. I needed only a flag if the catch from library has occurred (which was not critical), and I planned to use/read this flag somewhere in the code below. Moreover, putting everything inside `try` block just might not fit into a current logic. And even if *could* be placed inside I don't think I *have* to do it - it's more about preferences than about design